# adjusting the baud-rate of pic24

Tags: microchip, baud-rate, pic24

i have a device outputting an data with 19200 baud.
The pic has been configured with SPBRG=12 BRGH=0 start and stop bits have been taken into account.

Nevertheless the pic doesn't receive the correct data! 
The data sent has been verified with hyper terminal and oscilloscope.

i can't find the error! Damn
any help?

Thx

Comment: Which PIC24 is this ?  I mean, the long number, like PIC24FJ256GB210

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the electrical, on some versions of PIC24 (actually I use dsPIC33, but they are much the same) there is also peripheral pin select to deal with. I also set TRIS appropriately, but I think that is not necessary.